# Which character in GoT does GRRM consider the most noble?

Tags: game-of-thrones

After so many years, we are nearing the end of *Game of Thrones*. It is probably clear by now that the most villainous of characters would include Cersei, and probably Tywin.

On the other hand we have characters who seem to be in flux and actually re-examining themselves, such as Jaime.

Some mostly follow in character, and no matter how thoughtful, fall astray from time to time, such as Tyrion and still others have the stamp of greatness, such as Daenerys, however flawed they might be.

**Has GRRM expressed an opinion about which of his characters are the "most noble"?**

Comment: Are you referring to GoT the TV show or GoT the book series (or both)?

Comment: sorry, my bad @Valorum. I meant the TV series. Although comments based on the book might be valuable. Txs for ur help in the formulation of this Q.

Comment: Depending on how you define Nobility Eddard Stark is probably up there but I kinda doubt GRRM has said much officially

Comment: IMHO the one of the main themes of Game of Thrones is that nobody is really all good or all bad. Cersei might appear villainous, but from her perspective she's looking out for her family, or getting revenge for somebody hurting her family. From her perspective, she **is** noble. By the same token, the "good guys" aren't perfect, and have their own flaws. I think this question misses one of the main points GoT makes.

Comment: I don't think it's all that clear that Cersei is supposed to be "villainous." I think that the point is that she is obsessively overprotective of her family, and this makes her a terrible ruler. Tywin is similarly obsessed with family, but in a different way. GRRM does this a lot - pairs of characters whose similarities and differences allow for interesting juxtaposition. Varys and Petyr, Robb and Jon, Arya and Sansa, etc. I would argue that the unambiguously honorable and evil characters were Eddard and Joffrey, and the fact that both are long dead is part of the point.

Comment: @Misha agreed. FWIW, I think this is actually not a bad question per session, I just doubt GRRM will have explicitly answered. Looking at inner monologues in the books might be the easiest way to know (because we see the real motivation for actions that way, at least as the character tells themselves), but the OP asked for Show only. If we can use book evidence, pretty clearly it's Ned or Barristan the Bold. Both have inner monologues that convey relatively pure intent.

Comment: Even though you would be asking GRRM to view things from the lens of the show characters, he'd probably have a hard time not imagining the characters he created and loves in the books. And, in many cases, they're very different from their portrayal in the show. Take Tyrion, for example. In the books he rapes prostitutes, orders executions and districts to be burned down, and killed a certain character purely out of maliciousness, which in the show, was portrayed as self defense.

Comment: I'm going to say Hot Pie.

Comment: Honestly have to go with Hodor. If you want someone who says more than one word, Shireen. If you want someone who is still alive, Sam.

Answer (score 10):

**Maybe none of them, or maybe all of them... with George everything is gray.**

A few of his own quotes on the struggle between good and evil:

- > My reading of history has shown me that simply 'being a good man' is not enough. That there are many kings who are good men and yet bad kings. And even good kings sometimes make disastrous decisions. So government is complex, politics is complex.
  >
  > <sub>Panel with R. Scott Bakker in Semana Negra, Spain (2008)</sub>
- > Nobody is a villain in their own story. We're all the heroes of our own stories.
  >
  > <sub>"George R. R. Martin Interview GAME OF THRONES" by Christina Radish, Collider (17 April 2011)</sub>
- > The battle between Good and Evil is a theme of much of fantasy. But I think the battle between Good and Evil is fought largely within the individual human heart, by the decisions that we make. It’s not like evil dresses up in black clothing and you know, they’re really ugly.
  >
  > <sub>"GRRM Interview Part 2: Fantasy and History", interview with TIME Entertainment (18 April 2011)</sub>
- > We all have good in us and we all have evil in us, and we may do a wonderful good act on Tuesday and a horrible, selfish, bad act on Wednesday, and to me, that’s the great human drama of fiction. I believe in gray characters, as I’ve said before. We all have good and evil in us and there are very few pure paragons and there are very few orcs. A villain is a hero of the other side, as someone said once, and I think there’s a great deal of truth to that, and that’s the interesting thing. In the case of war, that kind of situation, so I think some of that is definitely what I’m aiming at.
  >
  > <sub>AssignmentX interview (June 2011)</sub>

Comment: These are the correct quotes.

Comment: If I were to take a guess though, I'd say that based on the portrayal from the books, it would be Ser Barristan the Bold!